# How to set custom REQUEST header in PHP

Tags: php

In creating RESPONSE headers, using header() function will do the trick. How about for request headers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.omaroid.com/php-get-and-set-custom-http-headers/

Comment: Request headers are sent by the client. Are you talking about setting headers when using `curl`?

Comment: You want to spoof with currently running application? Or you want to emulate it request?

Comment: I am working with an MVC framework and I want to create my custom request headers in the controller function. When I use the header() PHP function, I can set my response header values easily. But for the request header...

Comment: How you gonna work with your new headers?

Comment: The custom header will be used for validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about making a request and specifying your headers, one way to do it is using [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$data = "<soap:Envelope>[...]</soap:Envelope>"; 
$tuCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/path/for/soap/url/");
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // if post request
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: \"/soap/action/query\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($data)));
$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl); 
if(!curl_errno($tuCurl)){ 
  $info = curl_getinfo($tuCurl); 
  echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url']; 
} else { 
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($tuCurl); 
} 
curl_close($tuCurl); 
echo $tuData;
```