# Setting headers which i request in php

Tags: php, http, header

Is there a way to set http request that i sent when i click a link on my page or post a form in php? For example my browser info, encoding type etc. sent when i ask to open a page. Can i add some extra headers. So i can set an header for security. I can check the header so i can understand that user come from a page that is in my server.

The `header()` set only response header. But i need to change my request header. I could not find a way yet. Is there anyone who has ideas about this?

Comment: You can do that via Javascript. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268673/set-a-request-header-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom REQUEST header in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846940/how-to-set-custom-request-header-in-php)